# Read first bytes of open file in Python without changing the file position

Tags: python, file

What would be the best way to read the first couple of bytes of an opened file without messing with the file position? Is this too much jumping around:

```
current_position = f.tell()

f.seek(0)
b1 = f.read(1)
b2 = f.read(1)

f.seek(current_position, 0)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why not store the first few bytes when you first open the file?

Comment: i see nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: The file 'position' you're referring to is just a small integer that acts rather like a bookmark. It's really not that big of a deal to move it.

Comment: it's a utility function that doesn't know what state the file will be in when it receives it. If the seek calls are random access this becomes a stupid question.

Comment: Well fair enough, just stick with what you've got already.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just me now knowing how file access works in general I guess.

Comment: You could use `os.pread` but that was only added in Python 3.3. Like this: `os.pread(f, 2, 0)` to read the 2 bytes at the start of the file.

Comment: Aha just the kind of thing I was trying to learn from this question @DanD. I would accept that as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`os.pread(fd, buffersize, offset)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pread) but that was only added in Python 3.3. Like this:

```
os.pread(f.fileno(), 2, 0)
```

to read the 2 bytes at the start of the file.

Another option would be to duplicate the `fd` and then seek on the duplicate and then close the duplicate:

```
d = os.dup(f.fileno())
os.lseek(d, 0, 0)
b1 = os.read(d, 1)
b2 = os.read(d, 1)
os.close(d)
```

Why can't file objects be duplicated directly?